# calculating the difference in milliseconds takes time

Tags: java, android, android-service

I didn't know how to properly title my question since I'm not sure what's wrong here, so I'll post my code with explanation what I'm trying to achieve..

I have a service that is running and sending event every second.. I need to have few checks in that process, each running after certain period of time, for example.. Each second I'm getting device attribute values, each 2 seconds I'm fetching "currentBox", each 5 seconds I'm checking network connectivity and each hour I'm trying to login..

this is the code:

```
private void startAutoUpdate() {
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (!connectivityHelper.isConnectedMobile() && !connectivityHelper.isConnectedEthernet() && !connectivityHelper.isConnectedWifi()) {
        eventBus.post(new Event(new ObjectConnectivity(connectivityHelper.isOnline(), null), Event.EVENT_TYPE_CONNECTIVITY_EVENT));
    }

    boolean localReset = false; // maybe  force was set after this started!!
    if (clearETags)
        localReset = true;

    try {
        try {
            if (localReset) {
                attributeValueRepository.clearETag();
                attributeValueRepository.clear();
                attributeValueRepository.fetchMeteoAttr();
            } else if (canUpdate(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.weather_update_delay)))
                attributeValueRepository.fetchMeteoAttr();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fail to load meteo attributes");
        }

        attributeValueRepository.fetchAll();
        Log.d("AVTEST", "Fetch all");
        try {
            if (localReset) {
                deviceStateRepository.clearETag();
                deviceStateRepository.clear();
                deviceStateRepository.fetchAll();
            } else if (canUpdate(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.state_update_delay)))
                deviceStateRepository.fetchAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fail to load deviceStateRepository");
        }

        try {

            if ((current - lastBoxCall) > 2000) {
                currentBox = restTemplate.getRemoteOnlyCopy().getForObject("v2/box", Box.class);
                if (currentBox != null) {
                    newSyncDate = df.format(currentBox.getSyncDate());
                    if (syncDate == null) {
                        syncDate = df.format(currentBox.getSyncDate());
                    } else {
                        if (!newSyncDate.equals(syncDate)) {
                            eventBus.post(new Event(null, Event.EVENT_TYPE_REFRESH_REQUEST));
                            syncDate = newSyncDate;
                        }
                    }
                }
                lastBoxCall = current;
                Log.d("AVTEST", "Fetch current box");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if ((current - lastNetworkCall) > 5000) {
                if (connectivityHelper.isConnectedEthernet() || connectivityHelper.isConnectedWifi()) {
                    try {
                        int timeoutMs = 1500;
                        Socket sock = new Socket();
                        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 53);
                        sock.connect(sockaddr, timeoutMs);
                        sock.close();
                        isOnline = true;
                        showNotification(true);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        isOnline = false;
                        showNotification(false);
                    }
                    connectivityHelper.setIsOnline(isOnline);
                    eventBus.post(new Event(isOnline, Event.EVENT_CONNECTION));
                } else {
                    connectivityHelper.setIsOnline(false);
                    showNotification(false);
                }
                lastNetworkCall = current;
                Log.d("AVTEST", "Check network connection");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if ((current - lastLoginCall) > 3600000) {
                restTemplate.login(restTemplate.getUsername(), restTemplate.getPassword(), restTemplate.getSerial());
            }
            lastLoginCall = current;
            Log.d("AVTEST", "Relogin");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "relogin error");
        }

        if (localReset) {
            clearETags = false;
        }

        errorCount = 0;
        previousCall = System.currentTimeMillis();

        eventBus.post(new Event(null, Event.EVENT_TYPE_AUTO_UPDATER_SERVICE));
        eventBus.post(new Event(new ObjectConnectivity(connectivityHelper.isOnline(), null), Event.EVENT_TYPE_CONNECTIVITY_EVENT));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "", e);
    }
}
```

So the point is, widgets on my screen should update after each event (every second), but from some reason they are delayed sometimes, so I debugged it. I found out that this section is causing the delay:

```
  try {
            if ((current - lastLoginCall) > 3600000) {
                restTemplate.login(restTemplate.getUsername(), restTemplate.getPassword(), restTemplate.getSerial());
            }
            lastLoginCall = current;
            Log.d("AVTEST", "Relogin");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage() != null ? e.getMessage() : "relogin error");
        }
```

I looked up in Android Monitor and this is the flow:

```
D/AVTEST: Fetch all
D/AVTEST: Fetch current box
D/AVTEST: Check network connection
D/AVTEST: Relogin
D/AVTEST: Home screen types update
D/AVTEST: Push logic: key: 2130968946, value: ViewHolder{3cec115 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1}
```

Last two ones aren't from this service, but it doesn't matter right now, the thing is, log stops before "Relogin" for like 15seconds and then continues.. Is it calculating this thing too heavy or what?

```
((current - lastLoginCall) > 3600000)
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is related to `restTemplate.login(restTemplate.getUsername(), restTemplate.getPassword(), restTemplate.getSerial());` ? Does it generate a Sync or an Async call?

Comment: Sync, but I don't understand why would it block the thread when that call will execute every hour..it should skip it every second the service is running and reaching that part of code?

Comment: If it's a Sync call it will block code execution until you receive a response. So it's normal for you to see the delay. I think that you might have another problem with `current` & `lastLoginCall`, you should setup a breakpoint in the line: `if ((current - lastLoginCall) > 3600000)` and check the variables value.

Answer (score 1):

You said the log stops before Relogin for 15 seconds or so.  My best guess is it's caused by restTemplate.login call--remember your "Relogin" log is after the restTemplate call.  This makes sense, since it depends on network connectivity and how fast the server response to your login request.

(current - lastLogin) will always be negligible.

Comment: But my login request will be called every hour.. that's why I'm checking that condition.. So if it's less than hour it will skip that line of code.. I don't understand why would it block the thread or whatever it's doing

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you perform network call in the service thread, so this code

```
restTemplate.login(restTemplate.getUsername(), restTemplate.getPassword(), restTemplate.getSerial());
```

execution takes a lot of time.

To fix it, make network call in another thread.

Also, maybe you should move you Log call to the time condition:

```
if ((current - lastLoginCall) > 3600000) {
                Log.d("AVTEST", "Relogin");
                restTemplate.login(restTemplate.getUsername(), restTemplate.getPassword(), restTemplate.getSerial());
            }
```

Comment: I'll try with that, but I don't understand why would it block the thread when that call will execute every hour..it should skip it every second the service is running and reaching that part of code?